# Trying to identify what military service, war and rank by the uniform

Tags: military, identification, naval, uniform

I have been searching google images, tried a reverse search and found nothing. I have looked on many sites and cannot identify the service. I do know he has 9 buttons on his coat, 3 on the cuffs, red under the gold on the collar but I cannot find anything about the hat with the white pom pom. I am thinking he may be before 1815. There is a name on the back burned into the wood frame John/Joan R Byrne and this series co 4.26 or zg.9228 . There is also writing I cannot make out but it appears to be a name Hxxxxxx Hxxxxxxxxx and then grandfather.

Is he from the United States or could he possibly be from England? I am leaning towards a US Naval officer.

[image: Military Man][image: name1][image]

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that the mysterious name (*Hxxxxxx Hxxxxxxxxx*) isn't [*Horatio Hornblower*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horatio_Hornblower) - a fictitious Royal Navy officer by C.S.Forester. The letter count matches.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think so.  The last name may have a double consonant maybe t's, l's or f's.  It is very old and most letters on the wood are covered with years of grime. That name is written and not burned into the wood.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - If it is, the portraitist certainly portrays him [far younger than ITV did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hornblower_(TV_series))

Comment: It might help a lot if you could tell us everything you know about this picture. Where did you find it, and what do you know/suspect about it and its subject?

Comment: @T.E.D.: As I recall, the final HH short story has Admiral (ret.) Hornblower unwittingly assisting, in 1848, a middle-aged Frenchman, in a rush to get to Paris "*because his time has come*". The Frenchman named of course *Charles-Louis Napoléon Bonaparte*.

Comment: Coat is similar to these rear admirals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gordon_(Royal_Navy_officer) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Baker_(Royal_Navy_officer)

Comment: It may also help if you edit your question to include a picture of the back of the frame.  People here may have more experience reading the writing.

Comment: I will try to get my daughter, if she comes over today, to take a clear picture and upload it today.  I too am thinking it's from the Royal Navy.  The hat on the table should be a clue of the time period, but we both have searched for one like that and found similar but not exact. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I hope this helps.

Comment: Picture of the name is far too small. First name could be Hilbert. Uniform looks second half of 19th century mainly based on the trousers. Not British Navy as would have rank insignia on sleeves. More likely army.

Comment: Why US or British as possible places he served? What country is the picture from? Most of Europe had uniforms similar to this, the name Hilbert (if his name) was used in several countries including the UK and Germanic countries.

Comment: I was thinking Royal Navy and my daughter thinks Mexican officer.  The picture is from the US as far as we know.  It may have traveled during its life. I was hoping the hat would be a distinguishing item to date the man. When we looked up uniforms we saw no hats with a white pom pom.  Thank you

Comment: last picture looks like a date 04.26.1728. Words above it appear to be a name, maybe the artist? It looks to be something like Jere? R ?????

Comment: @ jwenting ...which excludes US naval officer.

Comment: Is there anything I could use to clean off the grime on the names without damaging the frame or compromising the identification?  I appreciate all the help.

Comment: For the record, that is not a USN uniform; cuff and collar lace, plume on the hat, and the white sword belt are the dead give-aways. None were seen on USN uniforms.  Nor is the sword of a USN pattern.

Comment: I finally got confirmation from a Civil War Museum curator.  It took him some time to research, but it is a portrait of General Milo Hascall.  Now to find out who the artist was.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I doubt that this portrait is of Union Brigadier General Milo Smith Hascall (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milo_Smith_Hascall). The uniform depicted in the portrait shows quite a few discrepancies with the USA counter part. Furthermore, the face of the man in the portrait and that of the photograph in the link don't match up very well either. I'd suggest that the portrait is of a Latin American senior officer, maybe Mexican or Brazilian.